# Word for the period of graduate study prior to fieldwork, comprehensive exams, dissertation writing?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've forgotten the word commonly used to refer to the period during which a graduate student (doctoral candidate in particular) takes courses. Is it coursework? The sentence is:

Following my _____, I hope to conduct fieldwork in order to gather data relevant to my dissertation.

Comment: Yes.  Coursework.

Comment: Thanks. I'll wait to see if others agree. Appreciate your response.

Comment: You may consider posing this question over on [Academia StackExchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

[**Coursework**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coursework) is certainly one word that could be used to describe a period of in-class study:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : work that is assigned or performed as part of a course of study
>
> // The rigorous program combines *coursework* in . . . engineering and seminar classes in the ethical, legal, regulatory, communication, and business aspects of the biotechnology industry with over a thousand hours of research.
> — Angela Trepanier

This would be contrasted with the other word, [*fieldwork*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fieldwork):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : work done in the field (as by students) to gain practical experience and knowledge through firsthand observation
> **3** : the gathering of anthropological or sociological data through the interviewing and observation of subjects in the field
>
> //  an anthropologist who has done *fieldwork* in the South Pacific

Note that being *in class* doesn't necessarily mean being in a classroom. If a class goes on a field trip, for instance, they could still be considered to be in class and involved in coursework wherever they happen to be.

Of course, there are grey areas. If part of a class involves students being instructed on how to perform fieldwork, and they are taken out into the field as a class, they could be thought of as performing both classwork *and* fieldwork.

---

Other distinctions are *theoretical* study (book knowledge) and *practical* study (hands-on experience).

Answer (score 1):

***Pre-candidacy***

In a graduate program, at least in the United States, the major milestone is *advancement to candidacy.* Once this is achieved, the student enters a period that is obviously called *candidacy.*<sup>1</sup> In many programs, the period prior to this milestone does not have an official name. However, ***pre-candidacy*** is a logical name for it, which is indeed officially adopted by some programs (e.g. [UC Berkeley](https://grad.berkeley.edu/academic-progress/pre-candidacy/)).

<sup><sup>1</sup>It also has informal names, such as [ABD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_but_dissertation) ('all but dissertation'; see also [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28717/when-can-a-person-be-called-a-phd-abd/28727)). The precise details of who is and isn't considered a 'candidate' can [vary widely](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10972/phd-candidate-vs-phd-student).</sup>

In the context of your question, what should probably be in the '___' in your sample sentence is 'advancement to candidacy':

*Following my **advancement to candidacy,** I hope to conduct fieldwork in order to gather data relevant to my dissertation.*

Some notes on coursework and fieldwork:

1. Some doctoral students may choose to take courses (usually advanced, special-topics courses) even after they have advanced to candidacy and even after they have started writing their dissertation. But these are always optional courses; completing all *required* coursework is normally one of the preconditions for advancing to candidacy.
2. To do fieldwork, it is not always necessary to advance to candidacy or even to complete all required coursework. Some kinds of fieldwork may be doable e.g. in the summer, when there are no classes.